# Не работает код, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Выдает ошибку, не пойму в чем дело, подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  elem = document.querySelector('.box');

function myAnimation() {
  let pos = 0;

  let id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame(pos) {
    if (pos == 300) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
btn.addEventListener('click', myAnimation);
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё показать какую ошибку выдаёт в консоле

Comment: Я никакой ошибки не вижу. А вы?

Comment: оберните код в window.onload = () => {  тут ваш код  }

Comment: и все ок будета

Comment: Всё работает, просто уберите параметр в функции`frame(pos)`, зачем он?

Comment: у  автора была ошибка что не находит элемент

Comment: я код скопировал и вполнил и получи в консоль  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at data.js:54  а именно на btn.addEventListener('click', myAnimation);

Comment: автор сам писал ошибка в консоли и тут тока это ошибка может быть

Comment: @Санитариум, ну хорошо, добавьте скрипт после загрузки блоков и увидите, что он в любом случаи не будет выполнять задуманное :)

Comment: ну это да! но скрипт рабочий станет и ошибок нет если попытаться вывести console.log  то все отработает это в логике автора не все ок

Comment: @Санитариум, что за привычка всё подряд оборачивать в onload? Он тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: Ошибкy выдает в дебаггере, что document is not defined of object ( anonymous)

Comment: Спасибо с window.onload все работает как надо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
window.onload = () => {
  let btn = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  elem = document.querySelector('.box');

  function myAnimation() {
    let pos = 0;

    let id = setInterval(() =>{
      if (pos == 300) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        pos++;
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
      }
    }, 10);

  }
  btn.addEventListener('click', myAnimation, false);
}
```

все отличное отрабатывает

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> function frame(pos) {
> ```

```
function frame() {
```